# Clementine stops at the end ot a title

Tags: 18.10, clementine

Sometimes, when I reach the end of a track, Clementine waits and don't play the next track.

How can I fix this, so that Clementine will paly the next song?

---

Clementine Version: 1.3.1, Ubuntu: 18.10

Comment: Please note: it is not correct to say that clementine "freezes".  When we speak of programs freezing we mean programs becoming completely unresponsive to the point where you have to kill them from the task manager.  Clementine sometimes just pauses for no reason at the end of a track, forcing you to manually hit the "next track" button.